# How to Obtain Latitude and Longitude in Android

Tags: java, android, geolocation

How to obtain Latitude and longitude from the mobile device if GPS is not available... My mobile has internet Connection through wifi and gprs connection.... Can we get the lats and long from this?

Comment: Ave you read the Android Dev Guide article to the topic? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** :  [Network and also GPS Provider Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an)

Yes we cam...try this

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

// additionally (you have to implement LocationListener)
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0.0f, new LocationListener() ...)
```

After location you can use in locationlistener...

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {                          
         Log.d("a","onLocationChanged: lat="+location.getLatitude());
         Log.d("a","onLocationChanged: lat="+location.getLongitude());                 
    }
```

hope it helps..

Comment: Hello Uday,i used your code and included the implemented methods of locationlistener and i Tried Logging in all the unimplemented methods..but my code doest go inside any of the methods.... My Mobile just has wifi enabled....HTC WIldfire 2.2 Froyo....

Comment: I am not getting the coordinates... Is there some other way to obtain coordinates without using Locationmanager?

Comment: I got the coordinates by GPS but when i use NETWORK_PROVIDER then my tablet shows me that there is no provider available(while wifi is available on tablet)... and my android mobile doesnt show anything(it doesnt override any of the functions).......

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)

When you have a Location from the system. you can use methods getLongitude() and getLatitude()

For a full example have a look at [this code](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/NewTweetActivity.java) - lines 122-124 to set up receiving updates and lines 201-209 to get the Location.

Comment: Hello Heiko... i used ur code like Location location = getCurrentLocation(); which calls the getCurrentLocation(); and through this i am getting location value as null...i just have wifi enabled on my mobile...

Comment: Did you also start receiving location updates - as set up in lines 122-124 and as @Udaykiran has indicated in its first source listing in his answer?

Comment: I got the coordinates by GPS but when i use NETWORK_PROVIDER then my tablet shows me that there is no provider available(while wifi is available on tablet)... and my android mobile doesnt show anything(it doesnt override any of the functions).......