# How to obtain lats and long using the Internet ip address in android

Tags: android, geolocation

I need to obtain lats and long using the Internet ip address in android...
Like for example i have a Wifi Hotspot and my Device is connected to that Hotspot then is it possible to obtain lats and long using the ip address of that Current hotspot...?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other question: [How to Obtain Latitude and Longitude in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496949/how-to-obtain-latitude-and-longitude-in-android) , no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your android settings, you can allow the use of your wifi network to obtain your location in the location services menu. Then, when you use LocationManager to start location services (`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this)`), it will use your wifi to find it. Note that you will also need to add these lines at the end of your manifest file (before `</Manifest>`):

`<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following service IP to location:

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php